# postgres user restrict schema changes

Tags: postgresql

I need a postgres user who cannot alter tables, views, triggers etc. Only select & insert into tables, so I created new role and granted SELECT, INSERT, USE SCHEMA(something like that), SEQUENCE and even EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS privileges. But when I run function, I get following error: `ERROR:  permission denied for relation #table_name`.

Comment: What is the function trying to do to "#table_name" ?

Comment: Can you post the actual function? Also does it run with Security Definer or Security Invoker?